# Calculating linear regression with iteration in a loop

Tags: r

I'm working in R and I have 2 vectors, LE and NEE (of lengths 5265) with which I would like to calculate the linear regression between the two, but for 5 points at a time and put each 5 point regression coefficient value into another vector called WUE_5. This is the function I have for calculating the regression coefficient for all of the points:

```
WUE_function <- function(NEE, LE) {
  return(lm(NEE ~ LE)$coefficients[2])
}
```

I can't figure out how to write a loop that would essentially consist of

```
WUE_5 <- c(lm(NEE[1:5] ~ LE[1:5])$coefficients[2],
           lm(NEE[2:6] ~ LE[2:6])$coefficients[2],
           ..., etc)
```

I tried this with some arbitrary vectors x and y but this is the result:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 6, 3, 8)
n <- 7
i <- 1
z <- NULL


while(i < n){
  z[i] <- lm(x[i:i+4] ~ y[i:i+4])$coefficients[2]
  i <- i+1 
} 

z
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong that's making z filled with NA's
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You might want to consider an approach like this: `x <- runif(5000); y <- runif(5000); z <- sapply(1:(length(x) - 4), function(i) { x <- x[i:(i+4)]; y <- y[i:(i+4)]; lm(y ~ x)$coef[2] })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence operator `:` has high precedence then the addition operator `+`. This means that `i:i+4` translates to `i+4` (which is a single element).

If you did

```
z[i]<- lm(x[i:(i+4)]~y[i:(i+4)])$coefficients[2]
```

instead, I believe you will get the result you are after

Comment: I tried that and it worked..thanks so much!

However, when I tried applying it to my full vectors NEE and LE (which I should have mentioned have some NA values in them) it's giving me an error message. Is there something I can add to my code to get it to not calculate the linear regression if there are NA's in the 5 points?

Comment: @user3763919: By default, `lm` omits NAs, but I guess your errors arise when all your `x` or `y` are `NA`. You can either use an `if` statement to only perform the `lm` if there are no NAs in the subsets of `x` and `y`, or you can do: `z[i]<- tryCatch(lm(x[i:(i+4)]~y[i:(i+4)])$coefficients[2], error=function(e) NA)`. Note  that the latter will still fit models where there are NAs (using the subset that aren't NA), just not where _all_ the `x` or `y` are `NA`.